# change and update twilio serverless function

Tags: function, twilio, command-line-interface

I have deployed few functions in twilio serverless.If I mistakenly delet that local file from where I deployed the function.Or if this function is deployed by someone else.As there is no way to change the functions from UI,we must have to do it from cli.

The way I found is fetching,updating,building,deploying function by providing its service ,enviornment ,function ,build,deploy sid each time by function api by curl/twilio cli.Its very tedious and error prone to provide all those sid mentioned above. there should be an easy way just like when I have all the file locally and with a one twilio cli command I can change and deploy.

Whats the easiest way to download the  file  from serverless to local environment to change  and re-deploy it again from cli just like I did first time( just run twilio serveless:deploy )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify Twilio Functions (via the GUI) created with the serverless cli by sending the following request.

[Read only services and editing in the new Functions UI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/read-only-services-and-editing-functions-ui)

Example:

```
client.serverless.services('ZSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                 .update({uiEditable: true})
                 .then(service => console.log(service.friendlyName));
```

You can also use tooling for the severless API to make working with it incredibly easy, reference:

[Deploy Twilio Functions with the Serverless extension for VSCode](https://www.twilio.com/blog/deploy-twilio-functions-serverless-extension-vscode)

Comment: Great,But, Say for example ,i have lost all the files locally.And,I want to deploy the code from twilio cli again,is it possible to do that just by twilio serverless:deploy ?And most importantly  download those  file structure from serverless to local environment?

Comment: I imagine it is possible but I've not done it. The serverless API's are low level, so it requires a number of steps (which is what the serverless tool kit, https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit, addresses), https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api#api-reference.

Comment: This doesn't address the question but might be helpful for anyone dealing with twilio services. There's actually an API Explorer here https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/api-explorer/endpoints?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fapi-explorer

I found this a little less painful that creating a service to then manage other services :)